# android HelloFacebookSample facebook is not working in the second time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

HelloFacebookSample is working when I run it for the first time and fetch user data and get user info (name, photo), but when I try to run it for the second time, it does not fetch user info, and when I debug I found the user object = null

Can any one help?

Comment: Examples of facebook are very bad because in most cases not updated to the latest facebook sdk. It may be that the error.

Comment: @TeRRo Thanks a lot for your response, do you know any tutorial that can help me get user info (name, profile pic and email) from facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method of facebook sdk when you already have the user session

```
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {

                             Log.d("", user.getId());   
                             Log.d("", user.getName());                         


                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

ok to clear session you can use following code

```
Button close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                session = Session.getActiveSession();
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take example from following link.
I used it in my Application.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: I have followed the tutorial as you advice me and my code work only one time and them always return false when I check if session is open , please find my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508605/facebook-session-always-give-me-close-login-failed