# facebook session always give me Close Login Failed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have downloaded the latest Facebook SDK and I'm trying to get user info `session.isOpened()` is always false, can any one help here ?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button login;
    TextView name;
    TextView email;
    ImageView profile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // // Add code to print out the key hash
        // try {
        // PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        // "com.actelme.testfacebook", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        // MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        // md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        // Log.d("KeyHash:",
        // Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        // }
        // } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        //
        // } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        //
        // }

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // start Facebook Login
                Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true,
                        new Session.StatusCallback() {

                            // callback when session changes state
                            @Override
                            public void call(Session session,
                                    SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                                if (session.isOpened()) {

                                    // make request to the /me API
                                    Request.newMeRequest(session,
                                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                                // callback after Graph API
                                                // response with user object
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompleted(
                                                        GraphUser user,
                                                        Response response) {
                                                    if (user != null) {

                                                        name.setText(name
                                                                .getText()
                                                                + " "
                                                                + user.getName()
                                                                + "!");

                                                        email.setText(email
                                                                .getText()
                                                                + " "
                                                                + user.asMap()
                                                                        .get("email")
                                                                        .toString());

                                                        profile.setImageBitmap(getUserPic(user
                                                                .getId()));

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }).executeAsync();

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
    }

    public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {

        String imageURL;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userID
                + "/picture?type=small";
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL)
                    .getContent());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

**EDIT** I have applied your code but still not working

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Session session;
TextView name;
TextView email;
ImageView profile;
StatusCallback statusCallback = (new StatusCallback() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {

                        name.setText(name.getText() + " " + user.getName()
                                + "!");

                        email.setText(email.getText() + " "
                                + user.asMap().get("email").toString());

                        profile.setImageBitmap(getUserPic(user.getId()));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Restoring session");
            session = Session.restoreSession(getApplicationContext(), null,
                    statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Creating new session");
            session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Active session");
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Session is null --> " + session.getState().toString());
    }

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage() + " Cause: "
                    + error.getCause());
        }
    });

    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}

public Bitmap getUserPic(String userID) {

    String imageURL;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + userID
            + "/picture?type=small";
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imageURL)
                .getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Loading Picture FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

**EDIT2**

I have generated the key hash using this code as tutorial, and then add it to my app settings

```
// Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the native login facebook.

Button xml

```
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />
```

Code for the login activity:

```
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            DebugLog.log("Error: " + error.getMessage() + " Cause: " + error.getCause());               
        }
    });

    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new StatusCallback() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {

                           // Your code
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Code for the control session:

```
    session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            DebugLog.log("Restoring session");
            session = Session.restoreSession(getApplicationContext(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            DebugLog.log("Creating new session");
            session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        }
        DebugLog.log("Active session");
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    } else {
        DebugLog.log("Session is null --> " + session.getState().toString()); 
    }
```

Hope that help you

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggest and still it doesn't work

Comment: But you get the same error? Are you sure you have well put your key hash in Facebook App?

Comment: I have the following scenario, I have created FB application and then generate Keyhash and configure my FB app like tutorial, and then install my android application with old code and the facebook login screen shown and I add username and password and then it takes me to app permission and i allow FB app to access my info, and the user info come and I was able to show the name, and then i close the application and re-open it again, and when i do that the application is not running

Comment: OK, that is not saving the session or not being restored. In the code "Session Control" you are printing the Logcat?

Comment: I have logout from installed Facebook application, and then install my app and login with another facebook account, and it is also work for the first time, and then re-open the application and try to login again but this time I got a second error, "Invalid key hash, configure your app key hashes", althought I'm using the same application and it is already work in the first time ?

Comment: Check all configuration Facebook App, your "hash key" is generated from debug.keystore or generated as another keystore?

Comment: please check the second edit of the post, I have attached the code that generate key hash

Comment: I did I have replaces the package name with my own package name